# Get current session in WP admin

Tags: wp-admin, session, admin-init

Trying to access sessions in the WP admin and access a variable from it.

```
function tasks_admin_sessions() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'tasks_admin_sessions', 1 );

$nonce = $_session['wp_nonce']
$completed_url = admin_url( "post.php?post=$post_id&action=trash&_wpnonce=$nonce" );
```

but I get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _session

What am I missing in my code to get the session variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend. 
[How to use session_start in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797351/how-to-use-session-start-in-wordpress) and [How to use session in wordpress in plugin development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118817/how-to-use-session-in-wordpress-in-plugin-development)

It looks like your mistake is that you didn't capitalise "Session" when you declare the variable.

Instead of `$_session['wp_nonce']`, try  `$_SESSION['wp_nonce']`.

Comment: I wouldn't ask if I hadn't tried Google, will try that, but it shouldn't make a difference, I think I am adding the init wrong but will double check with caps

Comment: Google again - [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297007/why-are-some-variables-in-php-written-in-uppercase[link].